# Need advice how to start building a Java based web services

Tags: java, web-services

I want to build a Java based web services on Windows. This web service can run the local binaries on the web services server. This web service can be communicated by any internet browsers using XML messages.

I do not have any background on web services and very little knowledge in Java. Need advice and recommendation on how to start doing this task.

Any basic examples and tools are appreciated :)

Comment: it would help if you'd be a little more specific about (a) what you already know and (b) what you need to learn in order to accomplish your objective

Comment: I already had develop a DLL for IE browser using VC++. The DLL depends on local machine. Now I want to do this solution in the form of webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not have any background on web
>   services and very little knowledge in
>   Java.

I will suggest you to first [learn java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) and make your fundamentals of java more clear. Then start learning [Java Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119838/how-to-learn-java-webservices).

Comment: does it possible for a windows DLL to send XML messages to a Java based web service?

Comment: @karikari: I have never tried it. So can not comment much on it.